# Show that there are $t$ such that $f(x+td) \ge f(x)+(1-\sigma) t \nabla f(x)^T d$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am working on the following exercise:

> Take f : $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuously differentiable and bounded from below, with $\sigma \in (0, 1/2)$. Furhter consider the descent direction $d \in \mathbb{R^n}$ (i.e. $\nabla f \cdot d < 0$). At last let 
>   $$(A): \quad f(x+td) \le f(x)+\sigma t \nabla f(x)^T d$$
>   and
>   $$(B): \quad f(x+td) \ge f(x)+(1-\sigma) t \nabla f(x)^T d.$$
>   Show that $$T(x, d) = \{t > 0 \mid \text{$(A)$ and $(B)$ are satisfied}\}$$
>   is not empty.

By the Armijo rule I know that there is always a $t$ satisfying $(A)$. However I do not see how such a $t$ should also satisfy $(B)$. Could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce it to a one-dimensional problem by considering
the function $g(t) = f(x+td)$. Then
$$
 g(0) = f(x) \, , \quad g'(0) = \nabla f(x) \cdot d < 0
$$
and we are looking for values $t > 0$ for which
$$ \tag{*}
 (1-\sigma)  g'(0) \le \frac{g(t)- g(0)}{t} \le \sigma g'(0) \, .
$$

It suffices to show that there is a $t_0 > 0$ with
$$ 
\frac{g(t_0)- g(0)}{t_0} = \frac 12 g'(0)
$$
because then $(*)$ holds for all $t$ near $t_0$. To prove the existence of such a $t_0$ consider the behavior of 
$$
\frac{g(t)- g(0)}{t}
$$
for $t \to 0^+$ and for $t \to \infty$. For the latter use that $g$ is bounded below.